# eb init - ElasticBeanstalk application environment not showing up in the list of choices

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created an application and a corresponsing environment from AWS console.

I ran: eb init

But the ElasticBeanstalk application environment is not showing up in the list of choices.

Can someone help / point me in the right direction to help resovle this issue ?

Comment: Make sure you are using correct account/credentials and region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things you can try:

1. On your local computer check `~/.aws/config` and make sure you have the correct credentials set up. Your credentials should look like this:

```
  [profile my-profile-name]
  aws_access_key_id = AKBCDEFG1234567890
  aws_secret_access_key = abce123456ghijklmnop
  region = us-east-1
```

2. Run the init command with the `-i` flag to make sure you enter the interactive mode, and pass the profile name:

```
  eb init -i --profile=my-profile-name
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.
For me the issue was even after updating the right aws credentials when I was rerunning the `eb init` command it was outputting `Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (Y/n):` then I ran the command this way `  eb init -i --profile=default`. "default" was my profile